# looking for a better way to do the following

Tags: java

I need to parse numerous strings determining if they are int or double. Here is my current code that works with one. I want to be able to simply use the existing two try/catch to keep code tidy, rather than make one for all strings.

```
void camTestButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String cam01 = Cam0GO1.getText();
    String cam02 = Cam0GO2.getText();
    String cam03 = Cam0GO3.getText();
    String cam11 = Cam1GO1.getText();
    String cam12 = Cam1GO2.getText();
    String cam13 = Cam1GO3.getText();

    try {
        int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(cam01);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        try {
            double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(cam01);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {

        }
    }
    System.out.println(cam01);
}
```

I now have this working, yet I need to take the results and return to each individual textField?

```
    String cam01 = Cam0GO1.getText();
    String cam02 = Cam0GO2.getText();
    String cam03 = Cam0GO3.getText();
    String cam11 = Cam1GO1.getText();
    String cam12 = Cam1GO2.getText();
    String cam13 = Cam1GO3.getText();
    String[] cams = {cam01, cam02, cam03, cam11, cam12, cam13};

    for (String c : cams) {
        try {
            int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(c);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                try {
                    double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(c);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {

                }
            }   
            **System.out.println("Cam0GO01 = " + c.?? etc.);**
        }
```

Comment: use a `String array` &  a `loop`...

Comment: Make a method for it and call that method for all your texts.

Comment: What do you want to do with the int/double? That will really determine the best solution.

Comment: That worked, so how do i now pass the array to the individual strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void camTestButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    String [] array = {Cam0GO1.getText(), Cam0GO2.getText(), Cam0GO3.getText()};
    for (String st : array) {
        parseCam(st);
    }
}

public void parseCam(String st) {
      try {
          int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(st);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          try { 
              double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(st);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {}
      }
      System.out.println(st);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the type you've determined from a method. You could use a `String` or define your own `enum` or just use the built-in `Class`.

```
private static Class getType(String text) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(text);
        return Integer.class;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex1) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(text);
            return Double.class;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex2) {
            return String.class;
        }
    }
}

Class cam1class = getType(cam1.getText());
```

If you want to call this once for all the objects in the array then you could create a map with the result:

```
Map<String, Class> camTypes = Arrays.stream(camArray)
    .map(c -> c.getText())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getType));
```

Or if you have a `Cam` class with `equals` and `hashCode` defined you could use that as the key instead of strings:

```
Map<Cam, Class> camTypes = Arrays.stream(camArray)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), c -> getType(c.getText())));
```